# checking all values in an array with values of another array and get the results in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

My purpose is to access the array (exactSizedMaterialsData) which contains other arrays and check if its arrays 2nd value is equal to each value of array (exactSizedTypesDetected) and I want the results which satisfy the condition to enter the array (exactSizedItems). Below is how I did, please find the mistake and pardon me for being a newbie.

```
exactSizedMaterialsData.every(function(array){
 for (var i = 0; i < exactSizedTypesDetected.length; i++) {
   if(array[1]==exactSizedTypesDetected[i]){
     eval("exactSizedItems"+(i+1) + ".push(array) ");
     return true;
   }
  }
})
```

Comment: Check out `.includes()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: `includes` is unavailable in google-apps-script yet.

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Yes dude, your answer was very helpful for me and it did the job. I have a question and is really a noob one, what does  ~ do before a variable in a condition ?

Answer (score 0):

- `exactSizedTypesDetected` is 1 dimensional array.
- `exactSizedMaterialsData` is 2 dimensional array.
- When 2nd element of each element in `exactSizedMaterialsData` is included in `exactSizedTypesDetected`, you want to retrieve the element of `exactSizedMaterialsData`.
- You want to achieve what you want using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding for your question is correct, how about this modification? I think that there are several answers for your situation. So please think of this as one of them.

#### From:

```
exactSizedMaterialsData.every(function(array){
```

#### To:

```
exactSizedMaterialsData.some(function(array){
```

#### Note:

From your script, it seems that you want to retrieve only the 1st value which matched to `exactSizedTypesDetected[i]`. If you want to retrieve all values, how about the following script.

```
exactSizedMaterialsData.forEach(function(array) {
  var idx = exactSizedTypesDetected.indexOf(array[1]);
  if (~idx) eval("exactSizedItems"+ (idx + 1)).push(array);
});
```

- `includes()` has been added to ECMAScript 2015. Unfortunately, this cannot be used at GAS yet. This is also mentioned by [@I'-'I](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8404453/i-i).

  - So I used `indexOf()` instead of it.

#### References:

- [every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)
- [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)
- [Basic JavaScript features](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/#basic_javascript_features)
- [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)
- [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: I have done some changes and now exactSizedTypesDetected logs  [[Type 4 Sheets], [Type 2 Gola], [Type 1 Sheets], [Type 1 Gola], [Single Type Sheets]]
 Whereas the exactSizedMaterialsData logs [[sheets at upper, intermediate and lower, Single Type Sheets, Sheets, 8.0, 1.5, 5.0, , 3.0, Exact Sized Material # 1], [sheets at  back , Type 4 Sheets, Sheets, 8.0, 1.0, 2.5, , 1.0, Exact Sized Material # 2], [dfsdfdsfsd, Type 2 Gola, Gola, 5.0, 1.5, 2.5, , 2.0, Exact Sized Material # 3], [sheets at vertical divider, Type 1 Gola, Gola, , 1.5, 2.5, , 1.0, Exact Sized Material # 4],

Comment: [sheets at shutters, Type 2 Gola, Gola, 2.0, , 2.5, , 4.0, Exact Sized Material # 5], [sheets at shutters, Type 1 Sheets, Sheets, 8.0, , , , 12.0, Exact Sized Material # 6], [sheets at shutters, Type 1 Gola, Gola, 8.0, , , , 8.0, Exact Sized Material # 7], [sheets at shutters, Type 1 Gola, Gola, 2.5, , , , 8.0, Exact Sized Material # 8]]   and I have used exactSizedMaterialsData.forEach(function(array) {
  var idx = exactSizedTypesDetected.indexOf(array[1]);
      var exactSizedItems1 = [];
  if (~idx) eval("exactSizedItems"+ (idx + 1)).push(array);
      Logger.log(exactSizedItems1);

Comment: but exactSizedItems1  logs [] ie totally empty. Please check if I am committing a mistake.